# How to make a view know when a model instance in another view is saved

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-signals

I am working with  an API that does not send the response directly(maybe that's an api standard). For a crude example:

```py
def callbackview(request):
    #This view will receive the actual required data from the api server, and save response to 
    #the db(there might be a better way to do this)
    
    # Actually uses drf to parse/save the data
    ...
    return Response(...)
    
def apisenderview(request):
    #send the api request
    resp=requests.get("https://api_url.com/api",{"callbackurl":"callbackview",...})
    ...
```

The issue is that the response received by `resp` in `apisenderview` is simply the server queue details. What I think I need is a way for `apisenderview` to know when the API server has sent a response to `callbackview`. A solution I am considering is:

```py
...
def apisenderview(request):
    #send the api request
    resp=requests.get("https://api_url.com/api",{"callbackurl":"callbackview"})
    callbackinstance=None:
    while not callbackinstance:
        callbackqs=callbackmodel.objects.filter(queue_id=resp.queue_id)
        if callbackqs.exists():
            callbackinstance=callbackqs.first()
    
    #Continue with view operations
    ...
```

However, the solution above may have too many db calls(I haven't tested it yet).How do I optimize this process to ensure minimal `apisenderview` response time?

Comment: Just curious about the use case, why does `apisenderview` have to know? The other view operations there can be done in the callback right?

Comment: @bdbd The callback view is what the apiserver will send its response to. For instance, if I was showing hotel bookings, the `apisenderview` is the view that my user visits. The API request is sent and the `callbackview` receives the API response. However, my user who visited `apisenderview` still needs a response on available hotels, which was why the server request was sent in the first place.